# Simple dictionary of heterogeneous settings, ported from Clojure

Tags: swift, clojure

I am porting a Clojure program to Swift. Being a dynamically typed language, it is easy to throw different values together like this:

```
(def settings {:total-gens 5
               :name "Incredible Program"
               :options [:a :b :c :d :e]
               :final-comment "Hope you had a good time."})
```

I pass settings maps like this around in the program, and I wanted to have a fairly similar process in Swift.

Right away, I feel like I am fighting the type system and I'm wondering what is the most elegant way to do this.

Here are two options that were recommended to me, both of which seem verbose or strange:

1) First, make an `enum` type of all possible settings value types. Then, create a dictionary of `String: SettingsEnumType`. Every time I need to add a new type of value to my dictionary, I first need to change the enum definition, and then change the actual dictionary.

2) Instead, create an empty protocol with no requirements. Then extend values like Int, String, etc to adopt this protocol, even though it is really a "dummy" protocol. Then make my settings dictionary `String : SettingsProtocol` so I can add whatever type I want in there (after first extending the type).

Both of these options feel weird to me, like I'm trying to circumvent the type system rather than have it work for me. The second option is frankly silly, but would no doubt work as needed.

Are there any other possibilities for doing something like this? Additionally, would the String type be the only obvious type for the keys in a settings dictionary? In this case, Clojure has again spoiled me with the useful `keyword` type that simultaneously acts as a look-up function in addition to a value type.

Any advice/pointers appreciated as I consider this new language.

Comment: The *type* of the dictionary-value depends on  the *value* of the dictionary-index. Ouch! I don't know of how to express this neatly in any language. Yet it's clearly a common case. An  `enum` for the value type and, if need be, for the index type, looks simpler from afar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After referring to [Array with string and number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588465/array-with-string-and-number) answer, I believe you can create a Heterogeneous Dictionary with below Syntax:

```
let heteroDict = Dictionary<Any, Any>()
```

Can you try this one?